# Better way to check If model is exsiting then update it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Because I have unique key for the model,

If a new record trying to create with a  existed ** unique key**

It should be fail.

But I want the behavior be that

If (Create file) Then (Update the exsited record).

```
    begin
        Model.create(DATA)  
    rescue Exception => e
      Model.update(DATA)
    end
```

Is there any side-effect for my code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`find_or_initialize_by` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_initialize_by):

```
Model.find_or_initialize_by(key: :my_key) do |model|
  model.attr_1 = "New attribute 1."
  model.attr_2 = "New attribute 2."
  model.save
end
```

Also notice that it's generally not considered a good practice to rescue [`Exception`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Exception.html). You should probably be rescuing [`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html) or [`ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ActiveRecordError.html) instead, or at the very least [`StandardError`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/StandardError.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends a bit on your Rails version. In Rails 4 you would do something like this:

```
ModelName.where(attributes_hash).first_or_create
```

see Documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create